# How to remove blank line before prompt when I set fish_greating to null?

Tags: fish

I want to remove the blank line before prompt when I open a new fish shell window.

I try to remove `fish_greating` use official FAQ.

```
➜ set fish_greeting
```

Here's my plugins.

```
vue-multiple-pages on  master [!] is  v0.1.0 via ⬢ none 
➜ fisher ls
edc/bass
FabioAntunes/fish-nvm
matchai/spacefish
```

It works. I remove the greating "Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell".

But, I got a blank line like this:

[image: blankline]

How to remove this blank line?

======updated======

This is is gif that I want to explain.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If you press return to make a new prompt, does a new blank line appear? I want to know if it comes from the terminal emulator or the prompt.

Comment: No, I got this blank when I open the shell.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish You can see the gif I uploaded.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish I figure it out, thanks, bro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few hours of hard work, I found the answer.

It's the matchai/spacefish plugin which add new line to my prompt.

Here is the function

```
# Defined in /Users/liwei/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish @ line 1
function fish_prompt

  set -g sf_exit_code $status
    set -g SPACEFISH_VERSION 2.6.0

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Configuration
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  __sf_util_set_default SPACEFISH_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE true
    __sf_util_set_default SPACEFISH_PROMPT_FIRST_PREFIX_SHOW false
    __sf_util_set_default SPACEFISH_PROMPT_PREFIXES_SHOW true
    __sf_util_set_default SPACEFISH_PROMPT_SUFFIXES_SHOW true
    __sf_util_set_default SPACEFISH_PROMPT_DEFAULT_PREFIX "via "
    __sf_util_set_default SPACEFISH_PROMPT_DEFAULT_SUFFIX " "
    __sf_util_set_default SPACEFISH_PROMPT_ORDER time user dir host git package node ruby golang php rust haskell julia elixir docker aws venv conda pyenv dotnet kubecontext exec_time line_sep battery vi_mode jobs exit_code char

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Sections
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # Keep track of whether the prompt has already been opened
    set -g sf_prompt_opened $SPACEFISH_PROMPT_FIRST_PREFIX_SHOW

  if test "$SPACEFISH_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE" = "true"
        echo
    end

  for i in $SPACEFISH_PROMPT_ORDER
        eval __sf_section_$i
    end
    set_color normal
end
```

Just set `SPACEFISH_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE` to `false`,

add this line to your `config.fish` and solve the problem.

```
set SPACEFISH_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE false
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: I just wanted to say "thank you" for posting the solution to this.  I was getting the same behavior!

Comment: I also wanted to add that more options are documented in the Spacefish repo: https://github.com/matchai/spacefish/blob/master/docs/Options.md

Comment: @Jrop No thanks. Move on, dude. Better code, better world!